# Getting a max value from a node of XML in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, max

I have some xml like this

```
<variable>
  <historicDates>
    <item>
      <date>2012/01/13</date>
      <type>submitted</type>
    </item>
    <item>
      <date>2012/01/12</date>
      <type>required</type>
    </item>
    <item>
      <date>2012/01/11</date>
      <type>required</type>
    </item>
  </historicDates>
</variable>
```

I am trying to write a sql statement to get the maximum date where the type equals required. To compound the issue I the column is a nvarchar(max) so I know I have to cast it as xml even before I start.

I've tried to figure out the cross apply but cannot get it to work.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your XML is in a variable named `@xml`:

```
SELECT MAX(t.ItemDate)
    FROM (SELECT Tbl.Col.value('date[1]', 'datetime') AS ItemDate,  
                 Tbl.Col.value('type[1]', 'varchar(20)') AS ItemType 
              FROM @xml.nodes('//variable/historicDates/item') Tbl(Col)) t
    WHERE t.ItemType = 'required'
```

Since you indicated SQL Server 2008, you could also use a CTE here:

```
WITH cteXMLtoTable AS (
    SELECT Tbl.Col.value('date[1]', 'datetime') as ItemDate,  
           Tbl.Col.value('type[1]', 'varchar(20)') as ItemType 
        FROM @xml.nodes('//variable/historicDates/item') Tbl(Col)
)
SELECT MAX(ItemDate)
    FROM cteXMLtoTable
    WHERE ItemType = 'required'
```

Comment: Thanks Joe - Your the man!!  One more Add on - since I am trying to use this some ddl for a view, I don't have a variable @xml. Is there a way to just reference  a column line Cast(main.data as xml).nodes ...?

Comment: Not sure how that works for me.  I am trying to use this in a create view script to return a value for an associated row and and can't select and cast my nvarchar(max) column into @xml in my ddl script. Am I missing something?